# install lightgbm with gpu support on windows

Tags: r, windows, installation, gpu, lightgbm

I can install `lightgbm` from source from Windows Prompt

```
  A:\LightGBM>Rscript build_r.R
```

when I try to build with GPU support, I got this error:

```
CMake Error at A:/programas/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR filesystem system)
  (Required is at least version "1.56.0")
```

Then I tried to include boost dir, following https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/R-package. I got:

```
A:\LightGBM>Rscript build_r.R --use-gpu --boost-include-dir="/programas/boost_1_75_0/"
...
...
installing via 'install.libs.R' to A:/RLibrary/00LOCK-lightgbm/00new/lightgbm
Error in eval(ei, envir) : objeto 'programas' não encontrado
```

I´ve tried with/without `"/\`.
How to do it? Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `--boost-include-dir` needs to be an absolute path, like this:

```sh
Rscript build_r.R --use-gpu --boost-include-dir="A:/programas/boost_1_75_0/"
```